# Merge multiple spark rows to one

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like one given below. All the values for a corresponding `id` is the same except for the `mappingcol` field.

```
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------+
|misc                |fruit           |mappingcol          |id     |
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------+
|ddd                 |apple           |Map("name"->"Sameer"|     1 |
|ref                 |banana          |Map("name"->"Riyazi"|     2 |
|ref                 |banana          |Map("lname"->"Nikki"|     2 |
|ddd                 |apple           |Map("lname"->"tenka"|     1 |
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------+
```

I want to merge the rows with same row in such a way that I get exactly one row for one `id` and the value of `mappingcol` needs to be merged. The output should look like :

```
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------+
|misc                |fruit           |mappingcol          |id     |
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------+
|ddd                 |apple           |Map("name"->"Sameer"|     1 |
|ref                 |banana          |Map("name"->"Riyazi"|     2 |
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------+
```

the value for `mappingcol` for `id` = `1` would be :

```
Map(
"name" -> "Sameer",
"lname" -> "tenka"
)
```

I know that maps can be merged using `++` operator, so thats not what im worried about. I just cant understand how to merge the rows, because if I use a `groupBy`, I have nothing to aggregate the rows on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use by groupBy and then managing a little the map

```
df.groupBy("id", "fruit", "misc").agg(collect_list("mappingcol"))
.as[(Int, String, String, Seq[Map[String, String]])]
.map { case (id, fruit, misc, list) => (id, fruit, misc, list.reduce(_ ++ _)) }
.toDF("id", "fruit", "misc", "mappingColumn")
```

- With the first line, tou group by your desired columns and aggregate the map pairs in the same element (an array)
- With the second line (as), you convert your structure to a Dataset of a Tuple4 with the last element being a sequence of maps
- With the third line (map), you merge all the elements to a single map
- With the last line (toDF) to give the columns the original names

**OUTPUT**

```
+---+------+----+--------------------------------+
|id |fruit |misc|mappingColumn                   |
+---+------+----+--------------------------------+
|1  |apple |ddd |[name -> Sameer, lname -> tenka]|
|2  |banana|ref |[name -> Riyazi, lname -> Nikki]|
+---+------+----+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I have a lot of columns and i want to avoid adding them to the groupby. Is it possible using a self join by any chance?

Comment: I think the solution of @SCouto is a good approach, otherwise you might need more transformations to achieve the same result.

Comment: @CesarA.Mostacero is it possible to achieve this using window functions?

Comment: I think `window` function does not apply here. Basically the behavior that you want to achieve is: keep the same value for an specific key (composed key - 3 fields) and aggregate the values of one specific column, which is basically the solution by @SCouto.

Comment: Window function solution is possible, see latest answer. As a rule of thumb anything that a groupby can do, can also be done with a window function. The code is meatier but it gives you finer control over the process

Comment: Can someone suggest a Java example?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do the above with a Window function!

This is in PySpark not Scala but there's almost no difference when only using native Spark functions.

The below code only works on a map column that 1 one key, value pair per row, as it how your example data is, but it can be made to work with map columns with multiple entries.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

map_col = 'mappingColumn'
group_cols = ['id', 'fruit', 'misc']
# or, a lazier way if you have a lot of columns to group on
cols = df.columns # save as list
group_cols_2 = cols.remove('mappingCol') # remove what you're not grouping by

w = Window.partitionBy(group_cols)

# unpack map value and key into a pair struct column
df1 = df.withColumn(map_col , F.struct(F.map_keys(map_col)[0], F.map_values(map_col)[0]))

# Collect all key values into an array of structs, here each row
# contains the map entries for all rows in the group/window
df1 = df1.withColumn(map_col , F.collect_list(map_col).over(w))

# drop duplicate values, as you only want one row per group
df1 = df1.dropDuplicates(group_cols)

# return the values for map type
df1 = df1.withColumn(map_col , F.map_from_entries(map_col))
```

You can save the output of each step to a new column to see how each step works, as I have done below.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window

map_col = 'mappingColumn'
group_cols = list('id', 'fruit', 'misc')
w = Window.partitionBy(group_cols)

df1 = df.withColumn('test', F.struct(F.map_keys(map_col)[0], F.map_values(map_col)[0]))
df1 = df1.withColumn('test1', F.collect_list('test').over(w))
df1 = df1.withColumn('test2', F.map_from_entries('test1'))

df1.show(truncate=False)
df1.printSchema()

df1 = df1.dropDuplicates(group_cols)
```

Comment: in general window functions are costlier than group by