# Pyspark - collapse all columns in dataframe by group variable

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset that looks something like below.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
      ("001A", 105, "foo", to_date("2022-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd")),
      ("001A", 25, "foo", to_date("2022-01-01", "yyyy-MM-dd")),
      ("002B", 85, "bar", to_date("2022-02-05", "yyyy-MM-dd")),
      ("002B", 15, "bar", to_date("2022-02-05", "yyyy-MM-dd")),
    ],
    ["id", "num_col1", "str_col1", "date_col1"]
)
df.show()
+----+--------+--------+----------+
|  id|num_col1|str_col1| date_col1|
+----+--------+--------+----------+
|001A|     105|     foo|2022-01-01|
|001A|      25|     foo|2022-01-01|
|002B|      85|     bar|2022-01-15|
|002B|      15|     bar|2022-01-15|
+----+--------+--------+----------+
```

What I wanted to achieve is an aggregated form of `df` whereby I group by values in `id` and then aggregate across all the remaining columns in the dataframe. Therefore the resulting dataframe would look like this

```
+----+--------+--------+----------+
|  id|num_col1|str_col1| date_col1|
+----+--------+--------+----------+
|001A|     130|     foo|2022-01-01|
|002B|     100|     bar|2022-01-15|
+----+--------+--------+----------+
```

The dataframe contains a mixture of:

- numeric columns - which need to be summed
- string colums - which are always the same between groups - so just need to take the existing value
- date columns - which are also always the same between groups - so just need to take the existing value

The dataframe also contains many, many more columns so any method that involves writing out every single column will not work.

I have looked quite comprehensively across the net but have not found any similar questions or solutions that I have been able to modify to get it to work on my data.

I am quite new to PySpark so my attempts have been pretty futile but I have tried to use the `collect_set` function to collapse down each row into the groups, with the intention of applying a `map` function like here [Merge multiple spark rows to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003311/merge-multiple-spark-rows-to-one), however, it's been pretty unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dtypes` to classify, group by `string` and `date` type columns, and aggregate numeric columns respectively.

```
df = df.groupBy(*[t[0] for t in df.dtypes if t[1] in ('string', 'date')]) \
    .agg(*[F.sum(t[0]).alias(t[0]) for t in df.dtypes if t[1] not in ('string', 'date')])
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Used your template to get 90% of the way there. Learning about the * operator was a bonus.